# trying to post my blog collection to mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

i'm new to nodeJS. am trying a use post request to get the information the user post but am getting an error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'title'). please what am i doing wrong here.

here's my code

```
const express = require("express")
const app = express()
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const BlogPost = new Schema({
    title:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    content: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    body: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
})

const Blog = mongoose.model("Blog", BlogPost)
module.exports = Blog;

app.post("/blogs", (req, res) => {
    const blogs = new Blog({
        title:req.body.title,
        content: req.body.content,
        body: req.body.body,
    })
    blogs.save()
    .then(result => console.log(result))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
})
```

Comment: Can you post the front-end call where you make the call to `/blogs`?

Answer (score 0):

You may not get title from `req.body.title` that's why when you save this doc to mongodb it will throw this error.

For solution, you must check `req.body.title` before saving data into mongodb,
Otherwise, simply REMOVE  required: true from schema

```
title:{
    type: String,
    required: true
},
```

Comment: please i still don't understand what you mean

Comment: In req.body.title you may get Null or Undefine
that is the problem. To solve this issue you must check whether data is coming from req or not. got it @Emmanueluzoezie

Comment: thanks, have check the data is not coming

Answer (score 0):

To make this code to workable condition for that add `app.use(express.json())`

As we are accepting http request body value from postman , so that it will parse our http request into json payload,

Hence we can access the body parameters value by req.body..

```js
const express = require("express")
const app = express()
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// 2 json parsing
app.use(express.json())

//as my mongoose version is latest one so in that strictQuery is not supported
mongoose.set('strictQuery', false);

const BlogPost = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    content: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    body: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
})

const Blog = mongoose.model("Blog", BlogPost)
module.exports = Blog;

//3. connection bridge between applicaion and mongoose
const connectionUrl = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017'
mongoose.connect(connectionUrl, {
    useNewUrlParser: true
},()=>{
    console.log('Connected to MongoDB')
})


//Middleware

app.post("/blogs", (req, res) => {
    //console.log(req.body.title+ "  "+ req.body.content+ "  "+ req.body.body );
    const blogs = new Blog({
        title: req.body.title,
        content: req.body.content,
        body: req.body.body,
    })
    blogs.save()
        .then(result => console.log(result))
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
})

// 1.listen 
app.listen(3033, () => {
    console.log("Server is running on port 3033")
});

/**
 * use post request to get the information 
 * the user post but getting an error: 
 * TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'title').
 */
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vateH.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCVLq.png)